# How to catch radio button checked and continue to next page on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Starting my way on WPF world.
I created usercontrol with 3 radio buttons on it.
I want to create a scanario that when choosing one of the radio button - some other user control will shown on the window ( any radio button choose give different user control )

Someone have an idea how to do it ?

i want to use binding .. not use simple event that will popup new windows

Comment: Adding some of your code would be nice, so we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plain XAML approach**

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Option1" GroupName="Group1" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="Option2" GroupName="Group1" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="Option3" GroupName="Group1" />

    <l:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Option1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <l:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Option2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <l:MyUserControl Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Option3, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MVVM approach**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RadioButtonListItemStyle}"/>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedOption}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource YourDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

//your viewmodel needs to have propeties Options and SelectedOption. Your datatemplate selector then needs to choose datatemplate with right usercontrol based on selected option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RadioButton Checked event:

```
 private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Window win=new Window();
           win.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: i want to use binding .. not use simple event